# Why I'm getting choice not defined error?

Tags: python

I'm just starting with the python programming and trying Tic Toc game but I am getting choice is not defined error. My code is as follows://////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
board = [' ']*10
from IPython.display import clear_output
def display_game(board):
      clear_output()
      print(' _'+' '+'_'+' '+'_')
      print('|'+board[7]+'|'+board[8]+'|'+board[9]+'|')
      print('|'+'-'+'|'+'-'+'|'+'-'+'|')
      print('|'+board[4]+'|'+board[5]+'|'+board[6]+'|')
      print('|'+'-'+'|'+'-'+'|'+'-'+'|')
      print('|'+board[1]+'|'+board[2]+'|'+board[3]+'|')
      print('|'+'_'+' '+'_'+' '+'_'+'|')

def my_choice():
     choice = 'wrong'
     while choice not in ['X','O']:
            choice = input('Do you want to be X or O?')
            if choice not in ['X', 'O']:
                 print('Sorry, wrong input! Please try again!')
     return choice

 def choose_pos():
     choose = 'wrong'
     while choose not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
           choose = input('Which place you want to choose from 1 to 9 ')
           if choose not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
                   print('Sorry, wrong input! Please try again!')
          # else:
                #board[choose] = choice 
      return choose

 def display_update(choice,choose):
       board[choose] = choice 
  
 display_game(board)
 my_choice()
 choose_pos()
 display_update(choice,choose)
 display_game(board)
```

Comment: did you want to call `my_choice()` rather than `board[choose] = choice`

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
board[choose] = choice
```

The parameter `choice` is not defined in the scope of the `choose_pos` function.

It seems like you don't use the `my_choice` function at all.

Comment: I tried to define it as global but also no use. What I can do to eliminate this error?

Comment: @VaibhavShinde, well it's _not_ global. You're trying to access a local variable in another function. Please read the marked duplicate.

Comment: Solved, thanks. I stored the result of a function in a different variable and used that variable as a parameter for another function.